# What is causing this error when i try to deploy my django project to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deploying

ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.9.5 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, <3.7
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==304 (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==304
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to *************.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing pywin32==304 from the requirements.txt